# Moving Co-Ordinates of JavaFX text label recursively

Tags: recursion, javafx

My program takes a user value and passes the value through a method before returning a message on the GUI. I am wondering how I could be able to recursively move this message (called `displayResult`) value down along the Y axis in order to make room for new messages when the user calls the method again.

```
public class GuessingGameController extends Tab {

    Scene sceneOne;
    Scene sceneTwo;
    int choice;
    int generatedNumber;
    //private GuessingGame resetGuessingGame;

    public int generateRandomNumber() {

        Random randomNumber = new Random();
        int number = randomNumber.nextInt(50) + 1;
        return number;
    }

    GuessingGameController(Stage primaryStage) {

        GuessingGame guess = new GuessingGame();
        generatedNumber = generateRandomNumber();

        Label labelOne = new Label("WELCOME TO THE GUESSING GAME");
        setText("GuessingGame");
        Pane paneLayoutOne = new StackPane();
        Pane paneLayoutTwo = new StackPane();
        Button playButton = new Button("Click to Play!");
        Button quitButton = new Button("Quit");

        paneLayoutOne.getChildren().addAll(labelOne, playButton, quitButton);

        labelOne.setTranslateX(0);
        labelOne.setTranslateY(-100);

        playButton.setTranslateX(0);
        playButton.setTranslateY(0);

        quitButton.setTranslateX(0);
        quitButton.setTranslateY(50);

        setContent(paneLayoutOne);

        sceneOne = new Scene(paneLayoutOne, 400, 400);

        quitButton.setOnAction(e -> System.exit(0));

        playButton.setOnAction(e -> primaryStage.setScene(sceneTwo));

        Label userMessage = new Label("Please enter your guess here");
        TextField userInput = new TextField();
        Button guessButton = new Button("Guess");
        Button resetButton = new Button("Reset Game");
        Button backButton = new Button("Back");

        userMessage.setTranslateX(0);
        userMessage.setTranslateY(-160);

        userInput.setTranslateX(0);
        userInput.setTranslateY(-120);

        guessButton.setTranslateX(0);
        guessButton.setTranslateY(-80);

        resetButton.setTranslateX(0);
        resetButton.setTranslateY(-40);

        backButton.setTranslateX(0);
        backButton.setTranslateY(0);

        guessButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                int choice = Integer.parseInt(userInput.getText());
                guess.startGuessingGame(choice, generatedNumber);

                String endResult;

                endResult = guess.startGuessingGame(choice, generatedNumber);

                Label displayResult = new Label(endResult);

                displayResult.setTranslateX(0);
                displayResult.setTranslateY(150);
                paneLayoutTwo.getChildren().add(0, displayResult);
            }
        });

        //resetButton.setOnAction(e -> resetGuessingGame.resetForm(this));
        backButton.setOnAction(e -> primaryStage.setScene(sceneOne));

        paneLayoutTwo.getChildren().addAll(userMessage, userInput, guessButton, resetButton, backButton);

        sceneTwo = new Scene(paneLayoutTwo, 400, 400);
    }
}
```

Comment: What would the base case be?

Comment: I would like it to stop at around 200 on the x axis

Comment: Why not use a `ScrollPane` & `VBox` or a `TextArea` to display the results instead? Including a [mcve] may help us to better understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: If `paneLayoutTwo` **is** a `VBox`, you can add the new message to the top (thus pushing the older ones down) by calling `paneLayoutTwo.getChildren().add(0, displayResult);` Including the index in the method call allows you to add the item to the beginning of the `List`.

Comment: ^That is exactly what I would like to accomplish but I am wondering how I would do it recursively. I am using a Stackpane.

Comment: @GearoidSheehan - Please explain exactly what you mean by *"recursively"*.